# Random String generation from an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a code that asks the user to enter a present name and it's price and then stores this data in two arrays PresentArray_name and PresentArray_price. The PresentArray_name is generated randomly, and it's price is presented. I can get it to print the random present name but I can't the presents price to be printed. Should I be using a 2d array, and if so how would I do that? The code is below:

```
void add_presents()
{
    int i=0;
    char PresentArray_name[10][30];//A 2D array to store names of presents, 
which can only be 30 characters long
    int PresentArray_price[10];
    printf("This area is a little difficult to navigate as the answer for 
the question is stored before the question is displayed! Simply type in the 
toy hit the enter key, and then input it's price then hit the enter key! 
Don't pay attention to the headings!\n");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter present %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &PresentArray_name[i]);//Stores the presents in the 
PresentArray_name
        printf("Enter price for present %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &PresentArray_price[i]);//Stores the presents in the 
PresentArray_price
        if (PresentArray_price[i]<5||PresentArray_price[i]>15)
        {
            printf("Invalid! Enter a price between 5 and 15:\n");
            scanf("%d", &PresentArray_price[i]);
        }

    }
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Present %s costs %d\n", PresentArray_name[i], 
PresentArray_price[i]);//Prints the names and the costs of each present
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)(&t));
    for (i=0;i<total_number_of_presents_required;i++)//Loop counter form 
another part of the code
    {
        printf("Kid: %d gets %s, which costs: %d\n",i+1, 
PresentArray_name[rand()%10], PresentArray_price[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post sample data use as input, output seen and output expected.

Comment: So say if I put in the total number of presents required as 20, and then add the 10 different kinds of presents as: "A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J". Their prices being "5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15", and then ask it to generate the random present fro each kid, it does the perfectly fine. The output comes out as: "Kid %d gets %s [being a random present] 20 times. But the problem happens when the price of the present is asked to be displayed. The program displays the price inputted for the first present  as the price for a random present. For example Kid 1 gets G which costs 5.

Comment: It doesn't save the present's price with the present name

Comment: Legendary Assassin Hit  Your comment _describes_ the input and output.  Posting the true input used and output seen is more useful.

Comment: "I  put in the total number of presents required as 20" --> Better use the scenario matching code - which is 10.

Comment: BTW, Drop the `&` in `scanf("%s", &PresentArray_name[i]);`

Comment: "The program displays the price inputted for the first present as the price for a random present. For example Kid 1 gets G which costs 5" --> Of course it does with `PresentArray_name[rand()%10], PresentArray_price[i]` - they use different indexes.

Comment: Ok, so how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Use the same index for both arrays.

Comment: What should I change in the program?

Comment: I have kind of lost myslef in mhy own program 

Comment: `//` comments do not continue beyond the end of the current line. so this: `char PresentArray_name[10][30];//A 2D array to store names of presents, (newline)
which can only be 30 characters long`  does not compile.  There are lots of of similar non-compling lines in the posted code.

Comment: this statement does not compile: `printf("This area is a little difficult to navigate as the answer for
the question is stored before the question is displayed! Simply type in the
toy hit the enter key, and then input it's price then hit the enter key!
Don't pay attention to the headings!\n");`  Suggest breaking that text into: `"text" newline "moretext", etc to enter this very long line.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 2) when using the input format specifiers: `%s` and/or `%[..]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  Because those input format specifiers will always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any buffer overflow, which would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)(&t));`  this does not work as you are expecting.  suggest: `srand( (unsigned int)time( NULL ) );`

Comment: when entering a single `'` in a text string, always 'escape' it with a `\\` backslash

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 10, 20.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those magic numbers meaningful names, they using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the posted code needs to check the value in `total_number_of_presents_required` to assure it is <= 10

Comment: regarding: `printf("Kid: %d gets %s, which costs: %d\n",i+1,
PresentArray_name[rand()%10], PresentArray_price[i]);` do not use `rand()%10`  rather use: `i`

Comment: The code, as posted, does not compile!   Suggest fixing that problem.

Comment: the function: `srand()` should only be called once in the whole program, preferably very early in the `main()` function.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert a space: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: it is good programming practice to limit the 'scope' of a variable.  Currently, the variable 'i' is visible throughout the function.  Much better to remove the current declaration of 'i' and in each of the `for()` loops, the first parameter to the `for` should be: `for( int i = 0; ....`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips, also in stack overflow I tend to run out space for a line so it goes on to the next line but in my compiler the comments are comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the return value from the rand function, so you can use it both with the name and the price.

```
void add_presents()
{
    int PresentArray_price[10];
    char PresentArray_name[10][30];

    printf("This area...\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter present %d:\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &PresentArray_name[i]);

        printf("Enter price for present %d:\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &PresentArray_price[i]);

        if (PresentArray_price[i] < 5 || PresentArray_price[i] > 15)
        {
            printf("Invalid! Enter a price between 5 and 15:\n");
            scanf("%d", &PresentArray_price[i]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("Present %s costs %d\n", PresentArray_name[i], PresentArray_price[i]);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < total_number_of_presents_required; ++i)
    {
        int n = rand() % 10;
        printf("Kid: %d gets %s, which costs: %d\n", i + 1, PresentArray_name[n], PresentArray_price[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but the compiler comes out with an eeror of saying something like variable intialisation is only available in C11 or C99, which I don't really understand. The error appears in the first for loop

Comment: @LegendaryAssassinHit That is because you are not using this code.  You are using your own edited version of this code which you broke in the process of changing.

Comment: Jango, drop the `&` from `scanf("%d", &PresentArray_price[i]);`

Comment: Oh ok, but I did copy and paste this exact code, but I'll try it again

Comment: The compiler errors, and I quote: " 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in only allowed in C99 or C11 mode"

Comment: @LegendaryAssassinHit sounds like you're compiling in C89? You can solve that by compiling with the `-std=c11` flag for instance, or you can move the `i` declarations out of the `for` loops. That is, change `for (int i=0 .. )` to `int i; for (i=0 ...)`

Comment: How do i check what I am compiling in?

Comment: No problem! =] I forgot to tell you to compile with C11. Declaring variables only in the scopes they will be used is a very good practice.

Comment: yano, actually the & in the price shouldn't be dropped. Only the names don't require referencing in the scanf.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about `struct`s, I recommend using those, then you only have 1 data structure to keep track of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Present
{
  char name[30];  // note this will only hold a name 29 long to ensure room for NUL terminator
  int price;
};

int main(void)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  // now, you can simply create an array of this struct, and the name
  // and price will always be together
  struct Present presents[10];

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    // get user input. You should also check the return value of scanf which I'm omitting here for brevity
    // get the present name
    scanf("%s", presents[i].name);
    // get the price
    scanf("%d", &(presents[i].price));
  }

  // now when you randomly select a present, you'll get it's name and price
  i = rand()%10;
  printf("present name: %s\n", presents[i].name);
  printf("present price: %d\n", presents[i].price);

  return 0;
}
```

Using separate raw arrays for each data field doesn't scale well.  What if you also want to keep track of the present manufacturer's name?  Where it was bought?  The date it was bought? etc.. You can just add those fields to `struct Present`, and you still only have to deal with `presents` throughout the code, instead of a different array (and array name).

Comment: I tried your code, and seems to break the program, i don't really know why, but when the code is done making the total_number_of_presents_required, and then goes to this function the code breaks

Comment: @LegendaryAssassinHit Not sure what "break the program" means,, your code presented doesn't initialize `total_number_of_presents_required` (or even declare it), so if you're looping over that without initialization, that is UB and most likely going way beyond the bounds of the array (10). I thought you were primarily asking for advice on how to organize your data,, if that's not the case I should delete this answer.

Comment: when i say break I mean that the ouput does not appear on screen after the total_number_of_presents_required is entered. I didn't really ask for structuring my data, but the struct was really helpful in helping me learn, I just asked for how to print the price of the randomly generated present that is stored beforehand

Comment: @LegendaryAssassinHit whether you use a `struct` or 2 arrays, you have to use the same index to access the data. This is what chux was talking about in the comments. `rand%10` is not equal to `i`, unless by chance. If you want to see the 3rd present's name and it's price, then you need to access `[2]` of both your arrays or my struct. If you want to see a random index, then you'll need save the result of `rand()%10` and use that to index your arrays: `int n = rand()%10; presentName[n]; presentPrice[n];`